# What tools are best suited for managing/organizing bibtex references?

Tags: bibtex, citing, software

At the moment, I have a couple "master" bibtex files thematically organized into topics. But obviously this isn't ideal for a number of reasons.

While I use Zotero to manage references, it isn't ideal to export the relevant files each time. For me, anyway, Zotero is mainly a place to read and organize PDFs.

So that said, is there a generally-accepted tool to manage bibtex references?

Comment: Did you try JabRef?

Comment: If you are using Zotero, have you looked at [Better BibTeX for Zotero](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/)?